# How to calculate the recognition rate using Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: matlab, pca

In my matlab code, I have reached the point where I have projected the eigen faces and calculated the the minimum distance using the commands

```
euclide_dist = [ ];
for i=1 : size(En,2)
    temp = (norm(projtestimg-projectimg(:,i)))^2;
    euclide_dist = [euclide_dist temp];
end
[euclide_dist_min recognized_index] = min(euclide_dist);
recognized_img = strcat(int2str(recognized_index),'.jpg');
```

How do you go about calculating the recognition rate??

Comment: What do you mean by "recognition rate"? Also take a look at MATLAB's build-in [`pca`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html), that'd shorten your code appreciably

Comment: @Adriaan, the % of how accurate the `test image` is recognized??